# How to access a network folder from SharePoint 2013 using a service account

Tags: 2013, network-drive

I have a 3GB file which needs to be accessed via SharePoint 2013 site.

No problem to put it on a network drive and setup a link in SP.
However, that would require granting permissions twice for each user - to a SharePoint site and to a network folder.

Is there any way to access the file via a SharePoint (service) account and then giving it to people who have access to a site? Something similar to "Secure Store" target app for data sharing.

Any other ideas how to share a 3GB file through SP appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the user are signed in to the Active Directory, and the computer is in the same domain as the network drive, there are no need to sign in again. You could try that on a client machine and not from the server.

What you could do to improve findability is to give the SP_SearchContent account (your crawl account) read access to the network drive and crawl the content with the search service application. That way users can search for documents in the search center and make use of all the powers SSA have to give. It's easily set up and works as a charm. The best part is that it also takes document and folder permission into account, meaning users can only search for documents they have at least read access to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is not about signing in twice, but about setting permissions twice. The scenario would like this: 1) Upload the file to a network drive 2) Grant access to this file to a user 3) Display a link to the file on a SP site 4) Grant access to the SP site to a user. For every other user, if they want access the file via SharePoint, repeat 2) and 4). I am trying to find out a way of having only one step for that, instead of two.